# How to prevent Content type from appearearing in built-in Search results

Tags: views, nodes, feeds

I've got thousands of nodes which were created by importing using a Feeds module. I only want them to be searchable via the views search form, not by the built-in site search.

Is it possible to disable these nodes from being searchable by the built-in search, while still making it available to the search generated by a View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two modules you can check out.

[Search Config](http://drupal.org/project/search_config)

> Restrict search results by the content type. This is a role based
>   restriction.

[Search Restrict](http://drupal.org/project/search_restrict)

> Restrict by role who can search for each content type.
>
> Approach of this module is to re-write the search query, so that
>   content is indexed and available as search results to users in role(s)
>   that have permissions to view it, but not displayed to other roles.

OR

You can write your own query alter function.

```
function mymodule_query_alter(&$query) {
  $is_search = FALSE;
  foreach ($query->getTables() as $table) {
    if ($table['table'] == 'search_index') {
      $is_search = TRUE;
    }
  }

  if ($is_search) {
    $query->condition('n.type', 'node-type-name', '<>');
  }
}
```

And yes as webkenny suggested [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) as well.

> **Basic options**
>
> The module adds options to select:
>
> 1. which content type(s) to search,
> 2. which specific module search to use (node, help, user or any module that implements search),
> 3. advanced criteria
>
> For all these choices, there are options to switch between a select
>   box, checkboxes or radio buttons, and also customize the selector
>   label and the default - Any - text.

Comment: You totally won this one. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As we say in this community, "There's a module for that" - http://drupal.org/project/custom_search

Good module to add-on if you're using the core search module. Won't affect your views in any way since those are two different flows.